# How to create custom "summary/total" of a table

Tags: report, powerbi, dax

Say I have a table:

```
category    amount    
 A           10
 B           15
 C           20
 D           35
 E           10
 TOTAL       90
```

and I create a measure which is the sum of E & D minus the sum of A & B.

and I call this measure the my_total.

Now I would want the table to look like:

```
category    amount    
 A           10
 B           15
 C           20
 D           35
 E           10
 my_total    10
```

I can easily create this measure, and I have. but how can I edit the "summary or total" section of my table to do a custom calculation, using a custom row name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
my_measure = 
    IF ( 
        HASONEFILTER ( MyTable[category] ),
        SUM ( MyTable[amount] ),
        [my_total]
    )
```

Worked example PBIX file: https://pwrbi.com/so_55377007/

Comment: thanks for the solution. two concerns: the HASONEFILTER() is True because there is a row level filter, right? also: how am I able to change the name of *'TOTAL** to my measure name?

Comment: 1. Yes - why's that a concern?  
2. You can't.

Comment: You may wish to vote for this idea: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/34575985-rename-totals